# Make custom thumbnail size crop to EXACT dimensions

Tags: cropping

I've defined a custom image size like this:

```
add_image_size( 'home-promo', 456, 600, TRUE );
```

As you can see I've set the hard-crop parameter to `TRUE`, however it's still not cropping to this exact size. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image you are trying it on? What are the dimensions of resulting resized image?

Answer (score -2):

I thing, u need new php Class. Wordpress not support this function correct, cause wordpress try crop proportionaly whatever you do.